# SQL Recursive partial sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have two tables:

**MasterTable**

```
...
startSubNr
endSubNr
...
```

**Step**

```
...
nrFrom
nrTo
value
...
```

MasterTable contains for example:

```
startSubNr: 2
endSubNr: 16
```

Steps contains for example:

```
nrFrom: 2
nrTo: 19
value: 20

nrFrom: 1
nrTo: 2
value: 10

nrFrom: 19
nrTo: 5
value: 100

nrFrom: 5
nrTo: 16
value: 200

nrFrom: 4
nrTo: 5
value: 50
```

What I need is a sql query (which should work on SQL-Server and sqlite) to calculate the sum from a startnr to an endnr, where the number of steps can vary. The steps (from-to) are unique.

In this example it would have to sum up **20** (*2-19*), **100** (*19-5*) and **200** (*5-16*) while ignoring the values of 1-2 and 4-5.

Is there a way to do this in sql without having to use multiple queries?

Comment: Why you ignore other two values..?

Comment: Because in Mastertable I have startSubNr= 2 and endSubNr= 16. In the Steps table I search for a step starting with nrFrom 2 (nrTo is 19 and value is 20). Then I search for a step with nrFrom 19 (nrTo is 5 and value is 100) and so on. I do this until I reach a Step with endNr 16 and sum up the values of all steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREATE TABLE #Steps(nrFrom INT,nrTo INT ,value INT) DECLARE @Start INT = 2,@End INT = 16

    INSERT INTO #Steps(nrFrom ,nrTo ,value ) SELECT 2,19,20 UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,10 UNION ALL SELECT 19,5,100 UNION ALL SELECT 5,16,200 UNION ALL SELECT 4,5,50

    ;WITH _SumCTE (_From , _To , _Value )AS ( SELECT nrFrom ,nrTo,value FROM #Steps WHERE nrFrom = @Start UNION ALL SELECT _To , nrTo , value FROM #Steps JOIN _SumCTE ON _To = nrFrom and nrTo != @End

    )

    SELECT SUM(_Value) FROM _SumCTE
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the end point - if you add UNION ALL SELECT 16,4,500 to your data, it bombs out with max recursion

Comment: check for the end is really missing. Otherwise it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This recursive query does what you want I think, with a few provisos

- it will throw a max recursion error if it can't reach the desired endpoint (e.g. if @end is 1000)
- it assumes nrFrom is unique; if there are multiple "paths" out of a given nrFrom you will get odd results
- circular paths will cause a max recursion error
- sql is probably not the place to be doing this logic!

create table #step ( nrFrom int, nrTo int, value int );

```
insert into #step values(2,19,20);
insert into #step values(1,2,10);
insert into #step values(19,5,100);
insert into #step values(5,16,200);
insert into #step values(4,5,50);
insert into #step values(16,4,500); -- add this to check we dont go further once we reach 16

declare @start int = 2;
declare @end int = 16;

with cte(nrTo, val) as
(
    select nrTo, value
    from #step
    where nrFrom = @start

    union all

    select #step.nrTo, value
    from cte
    inner join #step on #step.nrFrom = cte.nrTo
    and #step.nrFrom != @end 
) 
select sum(val)
from cte
```

Comment: Is the level needed? You just need the value for the end point.